# Mindsphere; Mapping an aspect to a data source; can't link variables with the asset type

Tags: mapping, opc-ua, tia-portal, mindsphere

I'm new to the Mindsphere platform.

I'm trying to link the variables with the asset type but when I click on Change (wechseln) I get a blank white page.
I've already created an Asset (MindConnect Nano), an Aspect, a Type and an Asset Type.

I'm using Microsoft Edge. I've tryed to log in with a InPrivate; no benefits

Please see the pics, Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWiy9.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6v7yP.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I guess this was an issue related to Edge or Internet Explorer.
For best user experience use Google Chrome.

Comment: yes, it depends on the browser.
Thanks for your answer